# NSURLConnection and persistent connections

Tags: ios, network-programming, nsurlconnection

I have a question related to NSURLConnection and persistent connections.

Whenever NSURLConnection is cancelled, does it deletes the related persistent connection as well? or persistent connection will be retained until it expires?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cached persistent connection will be gone in a couple of seconds (and that nothing can be done to make it last longer).